# FSM aiogram команда для сброс состояния!

Tags: python, telegram-bot, aiogram

вопрос задаю с телефона, по этому код местами едет

Добрый день, ситуация следующая. Есть бот с состояниями, все отлично работает как нужно, кроме одного, не могу понять как сделать сброс состояния. Ну, к примеру, я начал тест и на n вопросе решил остановиться и заново начать или вообще выйти. Как можно сбросить состояние командой?
*Прошу вас не ругаться, на это есть несколько причин:*

1. Я новенький в программировании, это мой первый язык и изучаю я его всего 5 недель
2. Этой мой первый вопрос на такого рода форумах.

Код, конечно, приложил - весь модуль, кроме импортов, но не думаю, что это критично будет.

```
    report_data = {}
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(Command('report'))
    async def calculate_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        check = message.from_user.id  # проверяем доступ пользователя
        if check in config.usr_admins:
            await bot.send_message(chat_id=INFO,
                                   text=f' Репорт [{message.from_user.full_name, message.from_user.id}]')
    
    
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM otchet")
            conn.commit()
    
            await message.answer(f"\n\n ФОРМИРОВАНИЕ ОТЧЕТА ️")
            try:
                await message.answer(f'\n\n В кассе остовалось : {cursor.fetchall()[-1][-3]} ₽')
            except IndexError:
                await message.answer(" ТАБЛИЦА НЕ ПОДКЛЮЧЕНА ")
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=INFO, text=' ТАБЛИЦА НЕ ПОДКЛЮЧЕНА!!!')
                pass
    
            await message.answer( f'{tx.instr_1}' )
            await fsm.Reports.R1.set()
    
        else:
            await message.answer('‍ В разрабоке!')
    
    
    @dp.message_handler(state=fsm.Reports.R1)
    async def input_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
        try:
            money_in_the_morning = int(message.text)
    
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f'{tx.err_or_1}')
            await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_1}')
            return input_report
    
        await state.update_data( money_in_the_morning=money_in_the_morning )
        await message.answer( f'{tx.instr_2}' )
        await fsm.Reports.R2.set()
    
    
    @dp.message_handler( state=fsm.Reports.R2 )
    async def input_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
        try:
            proceeds = int(message.text)
    
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f'{tx.err_or_1}')
            await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_2}')
            return input_report
    
        await state.update_data(proceeds=proceeds)
        await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_3}')
        await fsm.Reports.R3.set()
    
    
    @dp.message_handler( state=fsm.Reports.R3 )
    async def input_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
        try:
            cashless = int(message.text)
    
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f'{tx.err_or_1}')
            await message.answer( f'{tx.instr_3}' )
            return input_report
    
        await state.update_data(cashless=cashless)
        await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_4}')
        await fsm.Reports.R4.set()
    
    
    @dp.message_handler( state=fsm.Reports.R4 )
    async def input_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
        try:
            collection = int(message.text)
    
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f'{tx.err_or_1}')
            await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_4}')
            return input_report
    
        await state.update_data(collection=collection)
        await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_5}')
        await fsm.Reports.R5.set()
    
    
    @dp.message_handler( state=fsm.Reports.R5 )
    async def input_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    
        try:
            costs = int(message.text)
    
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f'{tx.err_or_1}')
            await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_5}')
            return input_report
    
        await state.update_data(costs=costs)
        await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_6}')
        await fsm.Reports.R6.set()
    
    
    @dp.message_handler( state=fsm.Reports.R6 )
    async def input_report(message: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
        try:
            fact = int(message.text)
    
        except ValueError:
            await message.answer(f'{tx.err_or_1}')
            await message.answer(f'{tx.instr_6}')
            return input_report
    
        await state.update_data(fact=fact)
        report_data = await state.get_data()
    
    
        async def start_report(report_data):
            money_in_the_morning = int(report_data['money_in_the_morning'])
            proceeds = int(report_data['proceeds'])
            cashless = int(report_data['cashless'])
            collection = int(report_data['collection'])
            costs = int(report_data['costs'])
            fact = int(report_data['fact'])
            cash_1 = proceeds - cashless                                # высчитываем наличку
            cash_2 = proceeds - cashless - collection - costs           # Остаток после инкс и доп расход
            kassa = money_in_the_morning + cash_2                       # формируем кассу
    
    
    
    
    
    ####################################################################################################
    
            form = f""" 
     {datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")}\n
            ОТЧЕТ        \n
    ↦ Выручка: {proceeds} ₽
    ↦ Безнал: {cashless} ₽
    ↦ Наличными: {cash_1} ₽
    ↦ Инкассации:{collection} ₽
    ↦ Доп. расходы:{costs} ₽
    ↦ Факт: {fact}₽
    
            """
    ####################################################################################################
    
    
    
            # Проверка по кассе
            if fact == kassa:
    
                await message.answer(f'{form}\nВ кассе: {str( kassa )}₽\nКасса ровная! シ ')
    
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=INFO,
                                       text=f'{form}\nВ кассе: {str( kassa )}₽\n'
                                       f'Касса ровная! シ ')
    
    
            elif fact > kassa:
    
                await message.answer(
                    f'{form}\nВ кассе {str( fact )}₽ '
                    f'\nДолжно быть {str( kassa )}₽\n'
                    f'Сумма больше на {str( fact - kassa )}₽')
    
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=INFO,
                                       text=f'{form}\nВ кассе {str( fact )}₽ '
                                       f'\nДолжно быть {str( kassa )}₽\nСумма '
                                       f'больше на {str( fact - kassa )}₽')
    
    
    
            else:
                await message.answer(
                    f'{form}\nВ кассе {str( fact )}₽ '
                    f'\nДолжно быть {str( kassa )}₽.\n'
                    f'Не хватает {str( kassa - fact )}₽')
    
    
    
                await bot.send_message(chat_id=INFO,
                                       text = f'{form}\nВ кассе {str( fact )}₽ '
                                       f'\nДолжно быть {str( kassa )}₽.\n'
                                       f'Не хватает {str( kassa - fact )}₽')
    
    
            priz = 9000
            difference = priz - proceeds
    
    
    
            if proceeds >= priz:
                await message.answer(' ПРЕМИЯ :\n\nУраа... '
                                     'Вам положена премия 500₽ за '
                                     'хорошую работу! \n')
                await message.answer('')
    
    
            elif proceeds >= priz - 1000:
                await message.answer(f' ПРЕМИЯ :\n\nВам положенно Такси в обе стороны! \n'
                                     f'До  не хватило {str( difference )} ₽   \n')
    
    
    
            elif proceeds >= priz - 2000:
                await message.answer(' ПРЕМИЯ :\n\n'
                                     ' Вам положенно Такси в одну сторону! \n')
    
    
            return
        await start_report(report_data)
        await state.finish()
    
    
    
        money_in_the_morning = int(report_data['money_in_the_morning'])
        proceeds = int(report_data['proceeds'])
        cashless = int(report_data['cashless'])
        collection = int(report_data['collection'])
        costs = int(report_data['costs'])
        fact = int(report_data['fact'])
        cash_1 = proceeds - cashless
        # высчитываем наличку,
        cash_2 = proceeds - cashless - collection - costs
        # формируем кассу
        kassa = money_in_the_morning + cash_2
        check = message.from_user.id
        user = message.from_user.username
    
    
    
    
    
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO otchet VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
                       (f'{datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M")}',
                        check,
                        user,
                        money_in_the_morning,
                        proceeds,
                        cashless,
                        cash_1,
                        collection,
                        costs,
                        fact,
                        kassa,
                        kassa - fact))
        conn.commit()
```

Может тут и вовсе не стоило его добавлять, но на всякий, я добавил.

Answer (score 1):

state.reset() полностью сбрасывает стейт. state.finish() нужен если ты сохранял данные и хочешь завершить(например, опрос, а потом вытащить эти данные из памяти, сохраняются как словарь)

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [Постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию, изложите свои предложения](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше. Дополнить ответ можно, нажав [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1272139/edit)