# Как передать данные из aiogram state() в БД mysql

Tags: telegram-bot, telebot, aiogram, state

Есть бот который получает от пользователя данные имя, номер и вопрос, и передаем их в state(), затем выводит пользователю дабы проверил, все ли он ввел верно, а затем нужно передать их в БД.
Вопрос как передать эти данные из state() БД

вот пример самой библиотеки
https://docs.aiogram.dev/en/latest/examples/finite_state_machine_example.html
но тут нету отправки в БД

Answer (score 0):

для начало тебе надо сохранить в переменные данные ответы, они будут в словаре, дальше пишешь функцию , которая принимает данные переменные инсертит все в БД.

вот кусок моего кода который передает переменные в бд.
если сможешь разобрать ,то поймешь , сама функия записи в самом низу [FSM aiogram команда для сброс состояния!](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1272054/fsm-aiogram-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b4%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d0%be%d1%8f%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f)